# php Captcha is returning the old value and checks the old value

Tags: php, html, css, captcha, spam-prevention

I am using this script : https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha

To make a captcha in php.

I have this codes :

```
session_start();
include_once 'simple-php-captcha.php';
$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
$code = $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];
if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                        if (isset($_POST['captcha'])&&!empty($_POST['captcha'])) {
                            $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
                            if ($captcha == $code) {
                                echo "Login";
                            } else {
                                $errors[] = "Capcha is Not True.";
                            }
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = "Enter capcha.";
                        }
        } else {
                    $errors[] = "Enter all.";
                }
}
```

And HTML form :

```
<form accept="" method="POST">
username: <input type="text" name="username">
password: <input type="password" name="password">
captcha:  <input type="text" name="captcha">
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']; ?>">
<input type="submit" class="Button" value="submit">
</form>
```

BUT

The problem is that every time i enter the captcha and submit the form, the newer captcha will be generated and the form allways return **NOT TRUE CAPTCHA** pm.

For example i open the page, and the captcha for example is : 52111,
(i enter it correct) then i submit, then i see error that the captcha is incorrect, because the newer captcha generated is another one like : 48852.

I mean every time the page generate a newer one , How can i fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You should save old captcha value, before check the form:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['captcha']) {
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
}
$code = $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];

include_once 'simple-php-captcha.php';
if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                    if (isset($_POST['captcha'])&&!empty($_POST['captcha'])) {
                        $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
                        if ($captcha == $code) {
                            echo "Login";
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = "Capcha is Not True.";
                        }
                        unlink($_SESSION['captcha'])
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = "Enter capcha.";
                    }
    } else {
                $errors[] = "Enter all.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach your full script. This code working. You have an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

add with JS some query string with current date in the chapacha so the image is deleted from the browser cahce:

```
$('img').prop('src',+"<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']; ?>?_="+new Date().valueOf())
```